# Appending to file only after closing and re-opening code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a program, in which client gets to write something, then this text gets sent to the server and server saves this string to a text file.
I tried doing this, but I have a weird problem, where the text only gets saved to a text file only after client closes and reopens the application. I tried googling but got nothing.

Here is client's code:

```
import socket

c = socket.socket()

c.connect(('my ip here',5050))
info = input(" <<<")
c.send(bytes(info, 'utf-8'))
```

and here is the code of the server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
print("Socket Created...")

s.bind((socket.gethostname(),5050))

s.listen(8)
print("Waiting for connections.")

while True:
  c, addr = s.accept()
  print("Connected with ", addr)

  info = c.recv(1024).decode()
  save = open("database.txt", "a")
  save.write(str(info))
  save.write("\n")
  save.close
  print(info)

  c.close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't call the close methods `save.close` nor `c.close` so the buffers didn't get flushed.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe Ive been thinking and struggling so much just because i forgot simple "()" at the end.

Comment: @S.Stashevski Use a `with` block, e.g. `with c:` and `with open(...) as save:` and the socket and file will be closed automatically when the block exits.